# when user closes the browser how to delete all information related to login user which has view only permissions

Tags: 2013, permissions, browser-compatibility, cache

we deployed a website which created with  publishing  template to internet,

1. it enable anonymous access
2. some users has view only permissions ( view item,open item, view application pages permissions level) access one of subsite inside this web application.

here when users access this site from Mobile devices like Android and authenticate to sub site and after they close the browser.

- when they re-open the browser and browse the website main page it asking authentication,
- when user clears the browser cache it it does not ask any authentication .

here how to clear the browser cache when user closes the browser.

when user closes the browser how to delete all information related to login user which has view only permissions.

Answer (score 1):

**clear user content from browser when browser is closed.**

**1 ) Google chrome**
open the Settings screen from Chrome’s menu --> Click the Show advanced settings link at the bottom of the Settings page --> Click the Content settings button under the Privacy header --> Under Cookies, select “Keep local data only until I quit my browser” and click OK. When you close Chrome, it will now automatically clear your cookies .

**NOTE : If you want to clear all your private data when you close Chrome, install the Click&Clean extension from the Chrome Web Store.**

Comment: in sharepoint site there is any settings to clear the cache when user closes the site

Comment: I have not tried it. but i searched a month ago regarding cache clearing in share point . refereed link : http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2013/10/12/clear-sharepoint-cache/

Comment: http://documents.software.dell.com/site-admin-for-sharepoint/5.2.2/user-guide/faq/how-to-clear-authorization-cache

Comment: the view only permissions user login to this site and when user close browser and re open why it asking again authentication?

even this site is allowed annonymous user access enabled